# Xcode and admob first time what to do?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, admob

I just finish my first app on Xcode and I'm ready to summit it to the app store, but I want to add admob to it, so my questions are:
Can I add admob advertisement to it before I send it?.... I just don't want to update it as soon as it gets in the appStore.... that way I will make money since the first day!
My question is because at the moment of registering the app in admob it ask for the app store info (App Store URL:), if I create my site in admob with out this, will it work? or I really need to send my app to the appStore first, get up there and then get that URL, add admob to my app and then update the app?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app store URL is optional, so you do not have to upload it first. Put AdMob into your app **before** sending it in for review.

Comment: @XenElement... so I won't have problems getting paid from admob since the appStore Url is not there? they go just by the app id? thanks for your help.

Comment: Exactly. It seems that it's more for organizational purposes. You should set up your app on admob and of course test the ads out before the you send it.